# How to get first row value from JTable

Tags: java, swing

My question is that how to get first row value of jTable and display it in a textfield, but when ever the first row value changes, the value in the text field should change.

Comment: well... what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have made a jtable and values get inserted and is shows but dont know how to display the first row element in the textfield

Answer (score 2):

First off - your table has a [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html).

You can access by calling

```
 TableModel tm = table.getModel();
```

That `TableModel` has a method `getValueAt(int row, int column)` - use this to collect data from your first row (index 0).

The `TableModel` further allows for a [`TableModelListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) to be added. That `TableModelListener` in turn receives [`TableModelEvent`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html).

Use the event data to figure out if the first row was affected by your change and then apply the changed data to your textField:

```
 public void tableModelChanged(TableModelEvent te) {
    if(te.getFirstRow() == 0) { //First Row changed
       //Receive Data and update TextField Here
    }
 }
```

Comment: Note that there is a difference between model indexes and view indexes. I think the user is referring to the first row in the view, not the model. Your example uses all model indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your specific case, I think this sounds like an application for using a `TableCellListener`, which will keep track of changes in your cell. Your `jTable` will fire a `PropertyChangeEvent`  which is used by the listener. You might take a look at [here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) and the code provided there to get the idea. Hope this helps in any way.

Comment: private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         node n=new node(Integer.parseInt(push.getText()));
        q.push(n);
        model=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{n.getele()});
     
        push.setText(null);
    }

Comment: private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       
         node n=new node(Integer.parseInt(push.getText()));
         
         q.push(n);
      
  model=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        model.addRow(new Object[]{n.getele()});
     
        push.setText(null);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for my jtable, how do I get to  the value of first row to the text field?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         node n=new node(Integer.parseInt(push.getText()));
        q.push(n);
        model=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{n.getele()});

        push.setText(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
     node n=new node(Integer.parseInt(push.getText()));
    q.push(n);
    model=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{n.getele()});

    push.setText(null);
}
```